# Can you get the "CREATE" statement for a domain in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, command-line

In PostgreSQL, for many objects like functions (among other things), there exists a way to get the CREATE command for that specific object (with functions you can use pg_get_functiondef(oid), for example). Is there any way to do this for domains? It must be possible, since pgAdmin III seems to be able to get these statements for domains, but I haven't been able to find how this is done.

Comment: For object types where there's no `pg_get_blahdef` PgAdmin usually borrows pg_dump code to do it.

Comment: Simply, there is none. To see which SQL's are running while retrieving the information you seek, try open log for all statements. To do that change log_statement = 'all' in postgresql.conf file. Now, you can play with pgAdmin.